# Some environment variables not as expected when running under Service Fabric

Tags: azure-service-fabric

When running a guest executable in Service Fabric I have noticed that some environment variables do not seem to be mapped to where I would expect them to be.

A few examples of these are that %appdata% didnt resolve to the usual: 
C:\Users\\AppData\Roaming
but instead resolved to somewhere deep inside C:/windows

I have also noticed that when running applications using Erlang that the '.erlang.cookie' file is usually placed in the user root:
C:\Users\.erlang.cookie
but instead is trying to be created in C:\Windows

Is there a reason to why these are changed in these ways and currently I am having to make the guest executable not use 'appdata' and grant it administrative privileges using a policy in the application manifest to give it write access to C:\windows to write the '.erlang.cookie'.

Answer (score 0):

That's because services run under the NETWORKSERVICE account by default.
You can do runas, or use the configuration system for settings.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-application-runas-security

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-fabric/service-fabric-reliable-services-configuration

Comment: The first link specified that I can run the main entry point as local user or administrator. What is the entrypointtype for the non-setup entry point in the application manifest? this seems to be missed from the SF documentation
<RunAsPolicy CodePackageRef="Code" UserRef="SetupLocalSystem" EntryPointType="Setup" />

Comment: EntryPointType="Setup" is for setup, EntryPointType="Main" (or omitting the attribute) is the main entry point, which is the non-setup entry point.